# Using JOIN to map from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 2 mysql tables, and I want to output the 3-rd.

table_names:

```
eid  name
100   car1
101   car2
102   car3
```

table_fuel:

```
mid fuel 
100  30
100  40
101  50
100  60
102  70
```

Output:

```
name  fuel
car1  30
car1  40
car2  50
car1  60
car3  70
```

What I want is a mapping between e.id and m.id in order to display name of the cars and not ids, what I tried is this :

```
SELECT n.name
     , f.fuel 
  FROM table_fuel f
 RIGHT 
  JOIN table_names n
    ON n.eid = f.mid
```

But I get  Error: Token mismatch. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why RIGHT JOIN? INNER JOIN will do fine here, and when you need an outer join, do a LEFT JOIN!

Comment: Note that `name` is a reserved word for some dbms products.

Comment: I don't think that query can generate that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple `JOIN` between the tables like

```
SELECT table_names.name, 
table_fuel.fuel 
FROM table_fuel 
JOIN table_names 
ON table_names.eid = table_fuel.mid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple LEFT JOIN for this:

```
SELECT n.name, f.fuel
FROM table_names n
LEFT JOIN table_fuel f ON n.eid = f.mid;
```

It's a lot shorter to use aliases than the full table names.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your table_fuel at left for Making Join statement :

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Fuel
FROM table_fuel b
LEFT JOIN table_names a
ON a.eid = b.mid;
```

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve error of token firstly Find the XAMPP php.ini file and uncomment by removing the semi-colon:

```
     session.save_path ="/tmp"
```

Then restart apache.

Then check your Query also.

```
            SELECT n.name
            , f.fuel 
              FROM table_fuel f 
              JOIN table_name n
            ON n.eid = f.mid;
```

Check Here [Demo](http://rextester.com/DMA45527)